# Arduino Code 'Bug'

Tags: arduino-uno, code-review

I'm sharing my code.. The problem I am facing is that the code performs all the functions that are to be called except showing the MAX30100 (for heart rate) readings. I have tried this code using statement switches,cases, if-else but couldn't figure out.  Can anyone help me out regarding this?

```
    unsigned long runGSR() {          

total = total - readings[index];         // subtract the last reading:

 readings[index] = analogRead(inputPin);  // read from the sensor:

  delay(100);

  total = total + readings[index];       // add the reading to the total:

  index = index + 1;                     // advance to the next position in the 

array:

  if (index >= numReadings)               //when the end of the array is reached

    index = 0;                           // wrapped around to the beginning:


  average = total / numReadings;           // calculate the average:

  return average;       // send it to the computer as ASCII digits


    } 
    void ambtemp()    

    {

       reading = analogRead(A2);       //takes the reading from analogue pin 2

  tempVolts = reading * 5.0 / 1024.0;   //converts the readings to volts

  ambitemp = tempVolts / 0.01;        //output voltage /10 millivolts = 1 degree 
C

  Serial.print(",Ambient Temp:");      //prints ambient temperature in serial monitor

  Serial.println(ambitemp);

  delay(10);         

    }

    void hbt()    //Function for heart rate (MAX30100) in which I am having problem
    {
        do
        {
            pox.update(); // Make sure to call update as fast as possible
            if (millis() - tsLastReport > REPORTING_PERIOD_MS) {   //the loop repeats every second 
            lcd.clear();
            Serial.print("HR:");
            Serial.println(pox.getHeartRate()); //prints Heart rate on LCD 
            delay(100);
            ambtemp();    //calls the ambient temperature function
            gsr = runGSR();   //calls the GSR sensor function 
            delay(100);
            tsLastReport = millis();
        }
```

Comment: You have two missing `}` Add them then use `ctrl+t` in ArduinoIDE to automatically format your code and then paste it again please. (Please use "code" function of the stackexchange editor to add code as code)

Comment: I try it but it doesn't work.

Comment: Any other solution... there is some kind of bug that is not plotting the readings of MAX30100

Comment: What I meant was "Show us your complete code in a way that we can run it on our Arduino simulators" Right now the code you pasted in the question does not compile. No one can help you right now. (You can Edit the question and change the code to the complete one)

Comment: `Serial.println(pox.getHeartRate()); //prints Heart rate on LCD` .... the comment does not match the command

Comment: When you say "I try it but it doesn't work" we understand the result but it isn't enough for us to help you.  For example, do you get partial output? If you try `lcd.print("HR:");` do you see that on the LCD? If not, then your hbt() function is never being called because there is no branching inside the function to keep that link from executing. We can't see enough of your code you be any more assistance.  Where did you get the sample you are using, what libraries are you importing, etc. Also, it looks like that 'DO' block has no WHILE / UNTIL  visible, is it an infinite loop?

Comment: I see the result "HR:" printed on lcd but it doesn't print the value of the sensor that should be 60-100 bpm. I have mentioned the main part of code and have already included required library needed for the code. What kind of error it can be that calls hbt function but does print its value?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use [this](https://github.com/oxullo/Arduino-MAX30100/blob/master/examples/MAX30100_Debug/MAX30100_Debug.ino) as source for your code:

This means that:

```
#include "MAX30100_PulseOximeter.h"
PulseOximeter pox;
```

Your issue is that the line:

```
Serial.println(pox.getHeartRate()); //prints Heart rate on LCD
```

Does not actually print anything on the LCD.
It only shows the value on the serial.

Try using [`lcd.print()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystalPrint)

Comment: No, its  neither print value on lcd nor on serial ide.

Comment: Paste your entire code in the question please.

Comment: Done. check now please

Comment: There are many many errors in your code. According to StackExchange rules you should provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that allows other people check for solution to your problem. Your example still does not compile and I can't test it.